# Analytical expression for distribution of a function of gaussian random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, gaussian-integral

Suppose I have two non-independent gaussian random variables:

$(T,C)\sim \text{BiNormal}[(\mu_t,\mu_c),(\sigma_t,\sigma_c),\rho]$

Let's also say the function $F(.)$ is the CDF of a Normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma$.

I would like to have an expression for $Pr[C<F(T)]$.

For this I can of course define $Z=C-F(T)$, and so the relevant question becomes: Can I derive an expression for the distribution of $Z$?

PS. I'm interested specifically in an expression for $C\in(0,1)$.

Comment: I don't know how to solve this but just wanna point out an oddity: If $F$ is a normal CDF, then $F: (-\infty, +\infty) \to (0, 1)$, so $C < F(T)$ is a bit of a strange event, right?  I mean $C$ has range $(-\infty, +\infty)$ but it is only compared against $F(T)$ which has range $(0, 1)$.  E.g. if $\mu_c \ll 0$ then this prob $\approx 1$ whereas if $\mu_c \gg 1$ then this prob $\approx 0$.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I’m interested in an expression assuming 0<C<1, which is of course not the full support of the distribution of C. I’ll add this as a note in the question. Thanks.

Comment: And $F$ is based on $(\mu, \sigma)$ which are different from the $(\mu_t, \sigma_t)$ of $T$ itself?  So e.g. $\mu_T$ can be sitting at a big fat tail of $F$ and $F(T)$ is some very non-linear transformation?  This is... not nice!  :)

Comment: Yes, $\mu$ and $\mu_t$ can be different... But I'd actually also find it helpful to have an expression for the special case $\mu=\mu_t$

Comment: If $\mu = \mu_t$ _and also_ $\sigma = \sigma_t$, then $F$ is the CDF of $T$ and $F(T) \sim Uniform(0,1)$, which is [nice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).  But even in such a nice special case, I don't know how to incorporate the effect of $C$'s non-zero correlation.

Comment: I wonder about your optimism that a nice closed-form exists. Is just obtaining efficient code for a numerical solution enough?

Comment: @JimB: yes, efficient code to evaluate numerically would also help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a numerical approach using *Mathematica*:

```
(* Define bivariate normal distribution *)
dTC = BinormalDistribution[{μT, μC}, {σT, σC}, ρ];

(* Parameters of interest *)
parms = Thread[{μT, μC, σT, σC, ρ, μ, σ} -> {0, 1, 1, 2, 1/2, 1, 1}]
(* {μT -> 0,μC -> 1,σT -> 1,σC -> , ρ -> 1/2,μ -> 1,σ -> 1} *)

NProbability[c < CDF[NormalDistribution[μ, σ], t], {t, c} \[Distributed] dTC] /. parms
(* 0.34283 *)
```

For the distribution of $Z$, random samples can be used to construct a nonparametric density estimate:

```
n = 10000;
tc = RandomVariate[dTC /. parms, n];
z = #[[2]] - CDF[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]] /. parms, #[[1]]] & /@ tc;
skd = SmoothKernelDistribution[z];
Plot[PDF[skd, z], {z, -10, 10}]
```

[image: Nonparametric density estimate of the distribution of Z]

*R* could also be used to provide numerical estimates.

Answer (score 0):

generic answer is $\int_0^1 dC \int dT p(C,T) \Theta (F(T)-C) $
where $\Theta$ is step function of zero for argument less than zero and one for argument greater than zero